# "debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed" :> google notebooks bash error

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

When trying to install basemap package on google cloud datalab's Notebook
I get following error. I want to plot a graph but it seems basemap is not installed.

```
%bash
echo 'Y' | apt-get install python-mpltoolkits.basemap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the command again. You may find that the install was successful the first time, but the full output was not shown.

```
>%%bash
>echo 'Y' | apt-get install python-mpltoolkits.basemap

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
python-mpltoolkits.basemap is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Unrelated to your issue, use `%%bash` instead of `%bash`. `%%<magic>` is for cell magic commands, while `%<magic>` is for line magic commands.